# timeline in animate doesn't seem to work

Tags: animate, timeline

I've been trying to animate in tikz a process that changes with time in an exponential way and I thought that the timeline option of animate could be useful. It seems, however, that it's not working or perhaps I don't understand the syntax. As i understand the following example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{smallsizepause.tml}
    :1:0
    :5:1
    :5:2
    :5:3
    :1:4
    :1:5
    :5:6
    :1:7
    :2:8
    :2:9
    :1:10
    :1:11
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \begin{animateinline}[controls=play,loop,timeline=smallsizepause.tml]{2}
        \multiframe{12}{iFrame=0+30}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];
            \draw[->] (0,0) -- (\iFrame:1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

should produce an arrow rotating with different speeds. The outcome, however, is the first 5 frames (until the angle 150) changing with the same rate (2). I can't get rid of the first frame too. Removing the timeline option makes one arrow rotating the whole way, but with constant framerate. What might be the reason for timeline not working the way it's supposed to?

Comment: Works for me. The rotating speed changes over the cycle. Make sure you are using the timeline file with the intended content. To ensure this, add option `[overwrite]`: `\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{smallsizepause.tml}`

Comment: Thank you: adding [overwrite] solved all the problems.